# MS-DOS copy command

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe

Hello this is something that has been on my mind for quite some time. How can you copy just say the first 5 files out of ten with one command. For example:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
file4.txt
file5.txt
file6.txt
file7.txt
file8.txt
file9.txt
file10.txt
```

how can I copy file1.txt through file5.txt only into

```
c:\users\person\desktop\folder\
```

Comment: `c:\users\person\desktop\folder\` is not a path we used to have in MSDOS? Are you sure you want to ask about MS-DOS (Pre most windows era) or did you want to ask about the command prompt. Which is not MSDOS. It might look the same but it is not.

Comment: You need real scripting capabilities for this. (PowerShell, Python or the like)

Comment: @DanielF Really? Are you sure? It's a one line command in a `cmd` shell.

Comment: @DavidPostill I stand corrected. I would have written a Python script for this task, unless on Linux.

Comment: @DanielF No worries. I just happen to know `cmd` reasonably well ;) If it was `bash` I probably could have done it after a lot of cursing/googling ...

Comment: @DanielF  you say "unless on linux", are you suggesting that if on linux you'd use bash?  You mention about what is required is powershell or python or the like.. you don't put bash there with those, do you?

Comment: @barlop I'm not fluent in `bash`, but am in Python. But for that task I'd rather run a shell script than a Python script. That is what I meant to say. I just couldn't see how `cmd` would be able to do this, and since it's easier to get Python running on Windows than a bash shell...

Comment: @DanielF if you know that bash can do it then you shouldn't just presume that batch can't. And btw, bash is pretty easy to get on windows. One way is cygwin which is almost a no-brainer to install for a windows command line  power user.

Answer (score 4):

#### How can you copy just say the first 5 files out of ten with one command

> How can I copy file1.txt through file5.txt only into
>
> `c:\users\person\desktop\folder\`

**Solution 1 - From a `cmd` shell**:

```
for /l %i in (1,1,5) do copy file%i.txt c:\users\person\desktop\folder\
```

**Solution 2 - From a batch file**:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /l %%i in (1,1,5) do (
  copy file%%i.txt c:\users\person\desktop\folder\
  )
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [copy](http://ss64.com/nt/copy.html) - Copy one or more files to another location.
- [for /l](http://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html) - Conditionally perform a command for a range of numbers.